# Derivative of maximum function coinciding at a maximal point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let a smooth function $f=f(x,t)$ be defined for$(x,t)\in \Omega\times[0,1)$ where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth bounded domain (and anything nice you'd like to assume about it). If we define $Mf(t)=\max_{x\in\Omega}f(x,t)$, then by the Lipschitz continuity of the maximum function (and the smoothness of $f$) we know $Mf$ is Lipschitz on $[0,1)$ (locally). Then, in particular, the derivative $Mf'(t)$ exists almost everywhere. Suppose the derivative exists at $t=t_0\in(0,1)$.

Next define $M_0=\{x\in\Omega\cup\partial\Omega|f(x,t_0)=Mf(t_0)\}$. This set is clearly nonempty. Then, is it possible to claim that there must exist $x_0\in M_0$ such that $Mf'(t_0)=\partial_t f(x_0,t_0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Omega$ is nonempty and compact, then the generalised gradient is given by
$\partial (Mf)(t_0) = \operatorname{co} \{ {\partial f(t_0,x) \over \partial t} \}_{x \in M_0}$.

In particular, $Mf$ is differentiable **iff** $\partial (Mf)(t_0)$ is a singleton.

Comment: What do you mean by "co"?

Comment: Convex hull. ${}{}$

Comment: So is the claim then that if $Mf$ is differentiable at $t=t_0$, then in fact $Mf'(t_0)=\partial_tf(x, t_0)$ $\textbf{for all}$ $x\in M_0$?

Comment: No. First all derivatives for $x \in M_0$ must be equal, and then $(Mf)'(t_0)$ equals any of these (same) derivatives.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused. You said $Mf$ is differentiable if and only if $\partial(Mf)(t_0)$ is a singleton. So doesn't that mean (due to the "only if" direction) that if we know $Mf$ is differentiable (i.e. $(Mf)'(t_0)$ exists), then $\partial(Mf)(t_0)$ is a singleton, and therefore all the derivatives for $x\in M_0$ coincide?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry, I misread your 2nd comment above which is correct.

Comment: OK great. Actually do you have a reference for this? I'm curious as to what the proof looks like.

Comment: I'd really like for it to be true, but it just seems odd to me that we can't have, at $t=t_0$, two different peaks (both a max), such that, one of those peaks grows, and the other diminishes as time moves forward. Then the derivative for one of those peaks would be positive, while the other would be negative, but the maximum as a whole would still be increasing since at least one of the peaks is growing....does this make sense?

Comment: The only one I can find at the moment is "Optimization and Nonsmooth analysis", Frank Clarke, Theorem 2.8.2, but it is not the most parsimonious result in that it is rather general and needs some parsing. If I get a chance tomorrow I will try to find a more succinct reference.

Comment: Don't confuse the derivatives with respect to $x$ with those with respect to $t$. If $Mf$ is to be differentiable, the derivative (with respect to $t$ at all maximising points (with respect to $x$) must be in the same direction otherwise $\partial (Mf)(t_0)$ will not be a point and $Mf$ will not be differentiable at that point.

Comment: Look at Theorem 2.1 in https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1975-205-00/S0002-9947-1975-0367131-6/S0002-9947-1975-0367131-6.pdf, it is a little more accessible.

Comment: It is a very useful and powerful theory but laden with technicalities. If the functions are convex in $t$ them things simplify considerably.